# Check If Record Was Inserted Or Updated In Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, trigger

I have created a trigger that if the length of `[name] <= 2` run an update statement.  This trigger fires 98% of the time, which leads me to believe the 2% of the time it does not fire means that the record was `Updated()` not `Inserted()`

This is sample DDL and my trigger, is there an issue with my trigger syntax?  Or should I be looking at a way to determine if the record was updated?

```
Create Table TwoNumericNames
(
  name varchar(500)
)

Insert Into TwoNumericNames (name) Values
('AA'), ('RR'), ('CC'), ('MM'), ('EE')


CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateName
ON [TwoNumericNames]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin

UPDATE [TwoNumericNames]
SET [name] = CASE
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%AA%' THEN 'Alpha Awe'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%RR%' THEN 'Raw Red'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%CC%' THEN 'Capt Cree'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%MM%' THEN 'My More'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%EE%' THEN 'Ed Ewe'
            END 
WHERE LEN([name]) <= 2

END
```

**EDIT**
Perhaps an `AfterInsert()` trigger would work better.  Is this the way it should be set-up?

```
Create Table TwoNumericNames
(
  id int,
  name varchar(500)
)

Insert Into TwoNumericNames (name) Values
(1,'AA'), (2,'RR'), (3,'CC'), (4,'MM'), (5,'EE')

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdateName] ON [dbo].[TwoNumericNames] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- get the last id value of the record inserted or updated
  DECLARE @id INT
  SELECT @id = [Name]
  FROM INSERTED

  -- Insert statements for trigger here
  UPDATE [dbo].[TwoNumericNames] 
  SET [name] = CASE
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%AA%' THEN 'Alpha Awe'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%RR%' THEN 'Raw Red'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%CC%' THEN 'Capt Cree'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%MM%' THEN 'My More'
                WHEN [name] LIKE '%EE%' THEN 'Ed Ewe'
            END 
  WHERE [id] = @id 

END
```

Comment: mame and name? typo?

Comment: Your trigger looks like it will update the entire table every time, doing a scan on the mame column looking for a string length of two or less. Shouldn't you be using the inserted table to restrict that to just the data that was inserted? Otherwise you are going to be looking at serious performance issues as the table gets larger, and incur blocking problems. And would you not want it to be an AFTER trigger? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131540/sql-server-create-triggers-on-insert-and-update

Comment: @donger - yes that was a typo

Comment: Nic - you are correct about it iterating the table each time, I had not even thought about that occurrence yet!  Looking at the link now.

Comment: Consider what you want the trigger to do if the length is less than two and doesn't fit your conditions, you may want to add `ELSE`

Comment: @Nic - see my edit.  Is that moreso along the lines of how the trigger should be done in order to not cause bottleneck and only update applicable rows?

Comment: If you have a trigger `FOR INSERT` then it won't possibly be called if someone `UPDATE`d the table. If you just have this set of 5 mapped values why don't you use a lookup table instead of manually changing every single entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have commented, you want to isolate your trigger to fire and modify only when necessary.  This means your going to have to filter on just the record that was inserted.  You can do this with the `inserted` view.  As you will see from the sample code below, I've slightly modified your code to more easily see what's going on and isolate the update statement to only affect the inserted row.

```
--create the table
create table TwoNumericNames (rowID int IDENTITY, name nvarchar(500))

--insert a row
INSERT TwoNumericNames
VALUES (N'AA')

--note the row
select * from TwoNumericNames;
go

--create trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateName
ON TwoNumericNames
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin

    UPDATE T
    SET T.[name] = CASE
                    WHEN I.[name] LIKE '%AA%' THEN 'Alpha Awe'
                    WHEN I.[name] LIKE '%RR%' THEN 'Raw Red'
                    WHEN I.[name] LIKE '%CC%' THEN 'Capt Cree'
                    WHEN I.[name] LIKE '%MM%' THEN 'My More'
                    WHEN I.[name] LIKE '%EE%' THEN 'Ed Ewe'
                    ELSE I.[name]
                END 
    FROM TwoNumericNames T
    JOIN inserted I ON I.rowID = T.rowID

END
go

--insert another row
INSERT TwoNumericNames
VALUES (N'RR')

--note only the one record is updated
select * from TwoNumericNames
```

Comment: There should be a "ELSE I.[name] on the end of that case statement, otherwise entries that don't fit in the case will write null values to the table. Also, be wary as this join could lead to multiple rows being updated if there are duplicate values of the rowID.

Comment: @Nic - agreed.  I assumed the OP wrote the CASE as intended.  The rowID should be a unique ID.  For the sake of simplicity I didn't make it an IDENTITY field. But you are absolutely correct.  I'll update accordingly.